# How to use Material UI from component library in a project with Material UI already?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI in my project and at same time, we have a component library (a npm package with many shared React components).

These components in the library are also based on Material UI.

So when I import these components from library to use in my project, it's duplicating the `<styles>` block to some component that're in use (for example `MuiButtonBase-root`).

Based on this, it's reseting some css styles, when the second `MuiButtonBase-root` come after.

Is there a solution for this?

---

Edit 1:

Here's an example, maybe components are not in this order, because I'm not really sure in which order the issue happen.

```js
// myProject
import { AppBar, Tabs, Tab, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Button, SharedComponentProvider } from '@shared-components'; // components based on MUI

function App() {
  return (
    <SharedComponentProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={fooTheme}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs>
            <Tab label="Item One"  />
            <Tab label="Item Two"  />
            <Tab label="Item Three"  />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>

        <Button>Click me</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </SharedComponentProvider>
  );
}
```

The `SharedComponentProvider` is like this:

```
import { StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  seed: 'shared-components',
});

function SharedComponentProvider({ children }: any) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={sharedTheme}>
      { children }
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Since `Tab` component is also based on MUI `Button` component, so it will create two tags of `<style>` with `. MuiButtonBase-root` inside, which can end up in this case.

Comment: Can you share some code snippets so that it becomes easier to understand the issue? Are you using Next.js, CRA or Gatsby? Are you using the [ThemeProvider](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#themeprovider)?

Comment: Sure, I'll do it

Comment: Are you importing the [ThemeProvider](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#themeprovider) in your application?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh yes, I updated it again with more details about providers

Answer (score 2):

Tonight I've had the same problem in MUI 5.x. and solved it by a litte library-component called `ThemeInheritor`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Theme, ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles";

export interface ThemeInheritorProps  {
  theme: Theme;
  children: React.ReactNode
};

export default function ThemeInheritor({ theme, children }: ThemeInheritorProps) {
  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

It just gets the theme of the application an provides it to the library 'world'.

After exporting this component to your application it should be integrated in the theming process at the head of the appliction like this:

```
import { ThemeInheritor } from "YOURLIBRARY";

...

<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
  <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
    <ThemeInheritor theme={muiTheme}>
    ...
    </ThemeInheritor>
  </ThemeProvider>
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

Where `muiTheme` is the theme created by the `createTheme()` function.

The `ThemeInheritor` provides the theme of the hosting application to all library components used in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in your project, change the prefix that is used for the generated CSS to avoid conflicts: https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator

Comment: I tried this solution before, but I couldn't add `StyleProvider` in root of my project, because it's gonna change className for components that aren't imported from `shared-components` too. Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: In your question, you have mentioned that you are importing component from `@material-ui/core` and `@shared-components`. Why don't you import and export the `@material-ui/core` components from `@shared-components` as well? In that way, you will using `StyleProvider` from a single place.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting **Button** and **SharedComponentProvider** components from the **@shared-components** package. You also need to export **ThemeProvider** from the **@shared-components** package.

This is because in your **@shared-components** package, you are wrapping your components with Material UI's **ThemeProvider**. You need to reuse the same provider inside your main application.

```js
import { AppBar, Tabs, Tab, ThemeProvider } from '@shared-components';
```

Comment: could you please explain this further with more details

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Nirmalya Ghosh is the correct way to do it.  As soon as you export the **ThemeProvider** from the **@shared-components** package it works.

In the **@shared-components** have the following

```
import { ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles";

export { ThemeProvider }
```

then in your main application have

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@shared-components';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myCustomTheme}>


    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        
      ...

      </header>
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

I've spent a while trying to solve this problem.